# How to inject JavaScript into an internet forum that parses URLs

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xss, code-injection

**Hypothetical scenario**

There's an interenet forum where typing a regular expression matched as a URL, such as

```
http://somesite.com
```

will become be made into a link in the HTML of the forum post once it is submitted. So the above link becomes

```
<a href="http://somesite.com">http://somesite.com</a>
```

If possible, I want to exploit this to get JavaScript into the `href` of the an `a` tag, i.e.

```
href="javascript:(function(){alert('Yo, dawg');}())"
```

The key is that I somehow need to get the expression

```
javascript:(function(){alert('Yo, dawg');}())
```

to do the equivalent, but to be recognized by the parser as a URL. How I can do that? Is there some way of doing it with escape characters, unicode or something else?

Comment: No, not unless you know what regex are they using to parse.

Comment: I am assuming they are using a server-side regex?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Assuming, for the sake of discussion, that it's `/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/`, then is this a solvable problem?

Comment: If you already know the regex, you can test it using a parser yourself! Test the pattern on regex101.com

Comment: Looking at the pattern, I don't think you can. The pattern does not accept the `javascript:` part.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/c7ygu43q/3/) is what you are asking for.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">
    http://www.example.com<br>
    http://google.com<br>
    google<br>
    object.property<br>
    http://www.ex-am-ple.com<br>
    www.test<br>
    http://text
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var div = document.getElementById("test");
var divContent = div.innerHTML;
div.innerHTML = divContent.replace(/http:\/\/(.*)\.(\w+)/g, '<a href="//$1.$2" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:(function(){alert(\'Yo, dawg\');}())">$1.$2</a>');
```